# Which is better for tracking?

Tags: tracking

I have access to a camera that is capable of both 1080p60fps and 4k30fps. Which would be easier to track details? The shot I'm using isn't shaky or anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1080p60 will give better temporal resolution, which is key for tracking details that move within the scene.  If the scene is ridiculously simple, such as if the only object moving at all is a Mac screen on a swivel, and if you can control the speed of the swivel however you like, then framerate is no longer the sole determinant of temporal resolution.  You can achieve the same temporal resolution shooting a half-speed move at 30fps as you can a full-speed move at 60fps.  In that case, shooting at 4K will give you greater spatial resolution than 1080p.

In the normal case, temporal, not spatial, resolution is the big bug-a-boo for object tracking.

Comment: My scene is the camera itself is still, on a tripod. I have a mac in front of the camera with a bunch of tracking dots on it. In the video, I swivel the mac around slightly, and slowly (to where there is virtually no jittering at 30fps) The effect I'm going for is tracking either blender then making it seem as if shattered glass is floating in front of the monitor. This means that I am doing object tracking, not camera. Is 1080p60fps still the wiser choice or 4k30fps?

Comment: I changed the answer to reflect the added information in the comment.